# Whose data is used running a vpn, your own or the vpn company's?

Tags: vpn, tunneling

I have gone through a lot of google pages explaining the finer technical points of a vpn, but none answer this question.

There's a lot of troubleshooting advice on stack, but this is not a troubleshooting question. Did get a load of info on what they actually do, but who pays for the constant tunneling of information from the users end through the vpn provider's networks after they have paid the vpn monthly costs? ie, can you cheekily browse the internet using their data?

Comment: You are aware that Stackoverflow ONLY deals with concrete PROGRAMMING questions. and hint: Companies normally are not run by idiots. If using a VPN per se would mean you bypass the data costs, the provider would be an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

You still transmit data, VPN is just one way of doing it, so you still have to pay for transfer done through VPN.